# __proto__ property is not visible in console in browsers

Tags: javascript

So I am aware about prototype and **proto**

```
function Vehicle()
{
this.brand=brand
}

const vehicle =new Vehicle("Ford")
console.log(vehicle.__proto__===Vehicle.prototype) // true
```

and when I print this I get this

[image]

Why I cant see the **proto** property ? .`Is __proto__ === [[Prototype]] ?`

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Comment: There is no `__proto__` property on these objects. It always was an [internal property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11003021/1048572) that just was displayed as such. Now the devtools display it more consistently like other internal properties with `[[…]]` syntax.

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

Comment: @Bergi yeah ok so why this vehicle.[[Prototype]] doesn't work

Comment: @WiktorZychla  but it used to be visible before ,and I remember it correctly

Comment: @gANDALF Because it's an *internal* property. `vehicle.__proto__` works (but is deprecated in favour of `Object.getPrototype`) because it's a getter inherited from `Object.prototype`. You can find it when expanding the prototype chain one step further.

Comment: Umm understood ,so `[[Prototype]]` is just for viewing ? we can't access it anyhow in the script? @Bergi

Comment: @gANDALF "*so why this vehicle.[[Prototype]] doesn't work*" two reasons: 1. it's not a correct syntax 2. It's only *displayed* as `[[Prototype]]` it's not actually called that. It shows *the* prototype as `[[Prototype]]`. Don't take the console representation as gospel. Consoles can format data however they like.

Comment: @VLAZ but still vehicle.prototype won't work too ,only vehicle.__proto__ will work ,and __proto__ is depracted too ,its bit confusing :D

Comment: @gANDALF `.prototype` only exists on the constructor, not on instances. That has always been the case. `__proto__` was an old way to get the prototype of an instance but it has been deprecated. `Object.getPrototypeOf()` is the correct way to get the same data. See also [Object.getPrototypeOf() vs .prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38740610)