# What does getPrototypeOf of a Class point to?

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(..)
```

returns the prototype (i.e. the value of the internal [[Prototype]] property) of the specified object.
so, the below makes sense

```
const prototype1 = {};
const object1 = Object.create(prototype1);

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(object1) === prototype1); // logs true
```

Even this looks fine

```
function fn() {
}
Object.getPrototypeOf(fn) == Function.prototype // logs true
```

But I am kind of confused why

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object) == Function.prototype // logs true
```

Please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some points to consider:

#### `Object` is a function

It can be used to convert a primitive to an object. Like `Object("test")` will create a `String` instance.

#### There is a constructor for functions

The constructor for functions is `Function`. It is not commonly done, but you can create a function by calling this constructor. For example: `new Function("alert('test')")` returns a function that when called will display an alert.

Functions which are created with `function` statements, expressions, arrow function syntax,... also have as constructor this `Function`. So for instance, `eval.constructor === Function` is a true expression. The same goes for `Object.constructor === Function`. You can do this for any function.

#### Where to find the a function's prototype object?

Like every constructor, `Function` has a `prototype` property. That object defines the prototype properties and methods that all functions inherit. We can find that prototype object via `Function.prototype`, or we can find it by taking a `Function` *instance* (i.e. a function), and getting its prototype object. This we do by calling `Object.getPrototypeOf` on a specific function.

#### Equalities

And so we can see that all of the following are equal:

```js
var a = Object.getPrototypeOf(eval);
var b = Object.getPrototypeOf(parseInt);
var c = Object.getPrototypeOf(function () {});
var d = Object.getPrototypeOf(RegExp);
var e = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object);
var f = Function.prototype;

// All true:
console.log(a === f, b === f, c === f, d === f, e === f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything in JavaScript inherits from `Object.prototype`. That is why everything in JavaScript is said to be objects. Even functions and arrays are objects under the hood.

So `Object.prototype` is the prototype of:

- `Function.Prototype`
- `Array.Prototype`

`Function.Prototype` is the prototype of `Function` and `Array`:

```js
Array.prototype.prototype == Function.Prototype // true
Function.prototype.prototype == Function.Prototype // true
```

And again, `Array` and `Function` inherits from `Object.prototype`:

```js
Object.getPrototypeOf(Array.prototype) == Object.prototype // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype) == Object.prototype // true
```

So to return to your question. The prototype of `Object` is `Object.prototype`. And `Object.prototype` is the prototype of `Function.prototype`, thus:

```js
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object) == Function.prototype // true
```

JavaScript is like a family tree:
`Object.prototype` had a baby called `Function.prototype`. `Function.prototype` then had babies of its own called Array and Function. And then follows arrays, classes etc... In the end, everything leads back to `Object`

Comment: *"The prototype of Object is Object.prototype. And Object.prototype is the prototype of Function.prototype, thus: `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object) == Function.prototype`"*: this is a faulty reasoning. It is like saying "O is a P, and F is a P, therefore O is a F". The outcome is of course true, but the reasoning is wrong.

Comment: I agree with your example, because you don't make a connection between O and F. But that is not the case in my example. In my reasoning, I make a direct connection between `Object` and `Function`. I wrote: "Object.prototype is the prototype of Function.prototype" which directly translates to `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object) == Function.prototype`. The reason I write "The prototype of Object is Object.prototype" is due to OP asking why `prototype` of `Object` equals the `prototype` of Function

Comment: *""Object.prototype is the prototype of Function.prototype" which directly translates to"*: eh, that phrase would translate to `Object.prototypeOf(Function.prototype) === Object.prototype`. You are also conflating `Object.prototype` with `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object)` which are two unrelated things.

Comment: Yeah, good point. So to clear up any confusions I've made: `.prototype` will get the prototype of a constructor function's instances. `Object.getPrototypeOf(object)` will get the prototype of the object, which you can also get from `myConstructor.__proto__`. So when you do `myConstructor.prototype`, you're not getting the prototype of `myConstructor`, you're getting the prototype of `myConstructor`'s instances instead. Correct? :-)

Comment: Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740610/object-getprototypeof-vs-prototype

Comment: *"`Object.getPrototypeOf(object)` will get the prototype of the object, which you can also get from `myConstructor.__proto__`"*: No, `myConstructor.__proto__` is the prototype object from which `myConstructor` was created, i.e. `Function.prototype`. It has nothing to do with `Object.getPrototypeOf(object)`.

Comment: You can get the `prototype` from which a constructor was created from both `Object.getPrototypeOf` and `.__proto__`:
`Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) == Function.__proto__ // true`

Comment: My comment was about your claim which I quoted, which is false. Now you write something different again, which is true. Let me refer to [an answer I gave on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work/42880438#42880438). Maybe it helps.