# On the prototype chain of an object, some objects' .constructor.prototype doesn't point to its [[prototype]], but points to that object itself

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-programming

The source object that printing the prototype chain can be various:

- `[1, 2, 3]` // array literal
- `{a: 1}` // object literal
- `new Set()` // built-in set
- `new Promise( () =>{} )` // built-in Promise
- `function foo(){}` // a function as object
- `window` // global window object from DOM

In effect, any object will be okay.

**My expectation is that this expression is always true:**

```
anyObject.constructor.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(anyObject)
```

Here is the code to print prototype chain and the constructor of every objects on the chain, and a tip to elaborate where that constructor points to.

```
function chain(o) {
    while (o) {
        console.dir(o);

        let tip = '';
        if (o.constructor.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(o))
            tip = 'points to the next object on the chain, i.e. its [[prototype]].';

        else if (o.constructor.prototype === o)
            tip = 'points to the above object itself.';

        else tip = 'NEVER EXECUTED TO HERE';

        console.log('Its constructor:', o.constructor, tip)
        o = Object.getPrototypeOf(o);
    }
}
```

Example results:

[image]

According to the results, we can find out that not every object on the chain is as my expectation.

How to understand this design?

Comment: Your equivalence isn't true for many built-in types.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @Barmar I understand, but that image is to stress those annotations on it. I still need to post that image even if I post the output as text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object.getPrototypeOf() vs .prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740610/object-getprototypeof-vs-prototype)

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine I think it doesn't. Because my question focuses on .constructor.prototype, not .prototype, as well as prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

> My expectation is that this expression is always true:
>
> ```
> anyObject.constructor.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(anyObject)
> ```

Well that expectation is simply wrong.

```
const anyObject = {constructor: null};
const anyObject = {constructor: {prototype: "something"}};
```

are trivial examples where it fails, however it is more customary to see

```
const constructor = {prototype: null};
const prototype = {constructor};
constructor.prototype = prototype;
```

where `prototype.constructor.prototype` points back to `prototype` itself, and has nothing to do with the prototype chain that `Obect.getPrototypeOf(prototype)` inspects.

And really just this circular reference can be found on virtually *any* `.prototype` object of *any* class, be it `(class {}).prototype`, `Array.prototype` or `Function.prototype`.

Your expectation holds only for instances that *inherit* their `.constructor` property, whose `.prototype` in turn points to the *[[prototype]]* of the instance.

Comment: Yes. The prototypal inheritance mechanism is designed for programmers to use. So modifying an object's prototype chain is normal, even for built-in objects. Thank you for your answer and for helping me edit my question!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*modifying an object's prototype chain is normal*"?

Comment: I mean, for example, arbitrarily set an object's `[[prototype]]` by `Object.setPrototypeOf()`. Meanwile, every object has its own constructor. That's to say, `anyObject.constructor.prototype` has nothing to do with  `Object.getPrototypeOf(anyObject)`.

Comment: Using `Obect.setPrototypeOf` is not normal - the *[[prototype]]* is normally determined at object creation and not changed later. But yes, it has nothing to do with `.constructor`

Comment: Oh, alright. So if I say using `Object.create()` to set `[[prototype]]`, this will be normal, right?

Comment: @ZhangWei Yes, that's more fitting